# Registered Customers vs Returning Customers?

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, customer-support

On our shopping cart we have two options at checkout.

```
1 ) Registered Customers

2 ) New Customer
```

Each shows a form to the user. I was just thinking that Returning Customers sounds better than registered customers?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, registered customers are those who you've already got their information (address, payment, login, etc.) on file and/or have created an account, while returning customers are simply people who have visited your site, have a cookie still intact on their system, and/or annonymously purchased from you in the past.

Usually "registered" implies customers are required to log-in at some point, "returning" customers does not.

Comment: From an analytics point of view I agree but not for sales. Not sure.

Comment: For your situation I guess the important question to ask is this - is it possible to be a returning but unregistered customer? Is there a difference?
Is it impossible to be an unregistered customer? If there is no possible confusion, then I'd say you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I like returning customer myself, the fact that they are a customer may imply that they have already undertaken a transaction with you.

I also like the idea of the 'Guest Customer/User' which means they do not need to register in order to use your service.  Although you can prompt them to register right at the end if you wish.